# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's dropdown menu in its top nav bar. You can see an example working here. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#

In mine, the arrow indicating that it's a dropdown shows on the menu but when I hover or click on it it doesn't reveal my dropdown links. I think I've included all the necessary classes, and I don't believe Twitter's requires javascript.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

My dropdown

```
  <div class='topbar' data-dropdown="dropdown">

  <div class='fill'>
    <div class='container'>
    <ul class="nav">

      <li><%= link_to 'Home', main_app.root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Outlines', main_app.outlines_path %></li>
       <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Assessment</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">second link </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">third link </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  ..... I go on to close all the divs etc. The nav bar looks great but the dropdown just doesn't work.
```

Twitter Bootstrap

```
<div class="topbar" data-dropdown="dropdown">
  <div class="topbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><a href="#">Project Name</a></h3>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="pull-left" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
      <ul class="nav secondary-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /topbar-inner -->
</div>
```

Comment: why vote down a question without leaving a comment?

Comment: the example you refer to does not have a dropdown menu (or it does not work)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It actually requires inclusion of Twitter Bootstrap's dropdown.js

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Comment: Where can I find bootstrap-dropdown.js ? it doesn't seem to be included in the default distribution

Comment: @Zen none of the sections under dropdown say that the js is not included in the main distribution.  No where in the dropdown related section does it say anything like "*.js must be included as it is not part of the main bootstrap.js"

Comment: @deltanine -  I was wondering the same thing and I saw this on their website: _"Plugins can be included individually (though some have required dependencies), or all at once. Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file."_ http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html

Answer (score 17):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

It's also possible to customise your bootstrap build by using:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

All the plugins are included by default.

Answer (score 1):

You must include jQuery in the project.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I didn't find any doc about this so I just opened a random code example from tutorialrepublic.com
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was the version of bootstrap.js included in my visual studio project. I linked to here and it worked great

```
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- core CSS -->
    <link href="http://webdesign9.in/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://webdesign9.in/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://webdesign9.in/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->       
</head><!--/head-->
<body class="homepage">
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" title="Web Design Company in Mumbai" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="The Best Web Design Company in Mumbai" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="term-condition.php">Terms &amp; Condition</a></li></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </nav><!--/nav-->
    </header><!--/header-->
    <script src="http://webdesign9.in/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://webdesign9.in/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.