# Dropdown menu using Twitter Bootstrap (JS and Jquery) doesn't drop down--what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm a complete newbie to website development, so I'm following patterns given by other developers. I'm following this [site](http://mifsud.me/adding-dropdown-login-form-bootstraps-navbar/) tutorial on how to add in a dropdown menu.

I found one question on stack overflow of another person following this tutorial. I've lost the link and despite looking through my history, I haven't been able to find it. Someone suggested that the tutorial was build using bootstrap's version 1, and to refer back to bootstrap site for more information. I did (my current version reflects using bootstrap's guide), but I wasn't able to glean any insight into why my code won't work.

After sifting through the bootstrap resources and similar stack overflow questions like

[Dropdown menu with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333940/dropdown-menu-with-twitter-bootstrap)

[Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051200/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu)

[Twitter Bootstrap 2 drop down menu is not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334205/twitter-bootstrap-2-drop-down-menu-is-not-work)

All seem to stress the importance of importing the jquery before bootstrap, so I've done this, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.  Here is what shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/louYJ.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KTown Car Share</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css"> </script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>


<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    Item1
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be most appreciated! I'm out of ideas on what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copy pasted your html and javascript into a jsfiddle and its working 
http://jsfiddle.net/daJT7/3/

Portion I copied:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });


<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                Item1
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I think it must have something to do with your references. One thing I did notice was that

```
<script src="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css"> </script>
```

Is invalid (script is for scripts, and you are already importing the bootstrap css on a different line). Remove this. This might or might not be causing problems.

As a side note. I wouldn't directly link to the twitter bootstrap github or someone else's website (unless flip.hr is your website :)).
Try using a CDN instead (e.g. http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ )

Comment: You were correct. I dinked around a bit with my references and one of them was the problem. Thanks so much for the heads up about linking elsewhere--duly noted and corrected. Thanks again!